# C# are these static methods thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, static-methods

I have this situation:

```
private static EntityBuilderCore entityBuilderCore = ServiceFactory.Create<EntityBuilderCore>();

private List<Set> SplitBySetId(List<Step> stepList)
{
    List<Set> outputSetList = new List<Set>();

    using (entityBuilderCore)
    {
        stepList.ForEach(step =>
        {
            // For each step, I find the corrispectives set's ids (one or more).
            // Then, I create the Set
            List<int> setIdList = entityBuilderCore.GetSetIdByStep(step);

            // Create Sets and adding to the output list
            setIdList.ToList().ForEach(id =>
            {
                if (!outputSetList.Any(set => set.Id == id))
                    outputSetList.Add((Set)entityBuilderCore.GetEntity(typeof(Set), id));
            });
        });
    }

    return outputSetList;
}
```

But I can have A LOT of steps subdivided in many Set... so I was thinking to parallelizate in this way (looks the add part):

```
private List<Set> SplitBySetId(List<Step> stepList)
{
    List<Set> outputSetList = new List<Set>();

    using (entityBuilderCore)
    {
        stepList.ForEach(step =>
        {
            // For each step, I find the corrispectives set's ids (one or more).
            // Then, I create the Set
            List<int> setIdList = entityBuilderCore.GetSetIdByStep(step);

            // Create Sets and adding to the output list
            var tempList = setIdList.Distinct()
                .AsParallel()
                .Where(id => !outputSetList.Any(set => set.Id == id))
                .Select(setId => (Set)entityBuilderCore.GetEntity(typeof(Set), setId));

            outputSetList.AddRange(tempList);
        });
    }
    return outputSetList;
}
```

But I'm not sure about the thread-safety of the entityBuilderCore. The core is this:

```
class EntityBuilderCore : CoreBase
{
    private static EntityRepository Repository;

    protected override string _connectionString
    {
        get { return ConfigurationService.Instance.GetValue("connessione_database_sinistriweb"); }
    }

    private EntityBuilderCore()
    {
        Repository = new EntityRepository() { ConnectionString = _connectionString };
    }

    public BaseEntity GetEntity(Type entityType, int id)
    {
        return EntityBuilder.BuildEntity(entityType, Repository.GetEntity(entityType, id));
    }

    // ...

    public List<int> GetSetIdByStep(Step step)
    {
        return Repository.GetSetIdByStep(step);
    }

}



class EntityRepository : RepositoryBase
{
    Dictionary<Type, string> tableDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

    public EntityRepository()
    {
        tableDictionary.Add(typeof(SQL), "PROCESSI.DBO.GFE_SQL");
        tableDictionary.Add(typeof(Step), "PROCESSI.DBO.GFE_STEP");
        tableDictionary.Add(typeof(StepSet), "PROCESSI.DBO.GFE_SET");
    }

    public DataRow GetEntity(Type systemType, int id)
    {
        string entityTable;
        tableDictionary.TryGetValue(systemType, out entityTable);

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE ID = @ID", entityTable), connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    DataTable entityDataTable = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    connection.Close();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(entityDataTable);
                    return entityDataTable.Rows[0];
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public List<int> GetSetIdByStep(Step step)
    {
        // bla bla
    }

    // ...

}
```

I will prefer to use only ONE entityBuilderCore also in the EntityBuilder class. I prefer to not instantiate every time the entityBuilderCore, I think is useless. But I'm afraid is not thread safety, because the SplitBySetId method is used by many **Task**s at the same time

```
class EntityBuilder
{
    public static BaseEntity BuildEntity(Type entityType, DataRow dr)
    {
        if (entityType == typeof(SQL))
            return BuildSQL(dr);

        if (entityType == typeof(Step))
            return BuildStep(dr);

        if (entityType == typeof(Set))
            return BuildSet(dr);

        return null;
    }


    //...

    private static Step BuildStep(DataRow dr)
    {
        using (EntityBuilderCore entityBuilderCore = ServiceFactory.Create<EntityBuilderCore>())
        {
            Step s = new Step()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ID"]),
                //... bla bla
            };
            return s;
        }
    }

    private static Set BuildSet(DataRow dr)
    {
        using (EntityBuilderCore entityBuilderCore = ServiceFactory.Create<EntityBuilderCore>())
        {
            Set s = new Set()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ID"]),
                //...
            };

            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's behind all these repositories? Entity Framework?

Comment: @Evk nope, I edited my question to show you

Comment: I can't really follow what's happening here since in the first few lines, I see a static field with an initializer followed by that reference being used inside a `using` statement. I can't think of many ways in which such code would ever make sense.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was editing somebody else's code, so maybe you can find some changies that sounds "stranges", but I'm working on it. I admit I'm not expert on static stuff, I'm learning now. So, I accept suggests of changes

Comment: I'm more seeing the problem can happen on the WHERE condition because as it goes parallel, the condition can be evaluated to true while there's another Task that is almost done in doing the GetEntity of the same setId.

Comment: Any performance increase for parallel execution will be lost when you start pulling items from sql one by one, if this is done on SQLite this will be terrible for performance. Also List is mutable object so it's not thread safe in the strict sense.

Comment: @FilipCordas this is right. And infact it was my first change: in the SplitBySetId I moved the *.GetSetIdByStep(step)* outside the *.ForEach* (and recalled *.GetSetsIdBySteps(stepList)*, so now I do just one first query.  
But I still need a the *entityBuilderCore.GetEntity(...)* in the stepList.ForEach . 
I have not mentioned that before for not lose the focus on my main question: the *entityBuilderCore.GetEntity*, is a good thing in the Parallel? Is better static or not?

Comment: Static wont make any difference. The important thing is [immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) If you don't change the state of the object you are fine. From what I can see `GetEntity` should be fine but the problem could be EntityBuilderCore because it has that static repository if this is a singleton you should make sure it [thread safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). But if you run this on a web server parallel will probably make the website run slower and there is a lot of room to optimize this code without parallelization.